# Kendo UI: Symbols are not being displayed

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

The time (clock) symbol is not displayed in the `TimePicker` widget of Kendo ui.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="kendo/styles/kendo.common.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="kendo/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="kendo/styles/kendo.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="kendo/styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/overrides.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">

    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="kendo/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="kendo/js/kendo.mobile.min.js"></script>
    <script src="kendo/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <input id="time" class="value" style="width: 90%;height:auto"/>
<script>
  var timepicker = $("#time").data("kendoTimePicker");
                     timepicker.value(t);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Include a reference to 'kendo.silver.min.css' file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.1028/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
```